# Switching between tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to development, and I need some help from you in working out the best way to show content from different tabs using Javascript. I would like to know how it can be done using Javascript/Jquery. Here is my HTML below. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<section class="payments-section">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#deposits" class="payment-tab-button">Deposits</a></li>
            <li><a href="#withdrawals" class="payment-tab-button">Withdrawals</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content-panel">

                            <!--Deposits Tab Content-->

            <div id="deposits">
                Deposit content goes here.
            </div>


                            <!--Withdrawals Tab Content-->

            <div id="withdrawals">
                Withdrawal content goes here.
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this. And as you haven't provided more code like CSS for example your problem can not be reproduced. 
And simple google search would [give you A LOT of examples and tutorials](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=css%20html%20JS%20tabs&atb=v210-1&ia=web) and after you decided for one and try to implement it, feel free to ask with provided code of your try.

I can point out to simple one I like: [W3-Tabs.](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tabulators.asp)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using jQuery. It's legacy technology. With ES6+ you can use many features jQuery offers, with pure JavaScript.

However, for simple Tabs you don't need any JavaScript. Just do them with some CSS + HTML: https://medium.com/allenhwkim/how-to-build-tabs-only-with-css-844718d7de2f